# How to write Data Transfer Object?

Tags: c#, .net, n-tier-architecture

In my N-Tier Architecture I have DTO (AddressResponseDTO) where i have some 20 properties. When presentation layer request(AddressRequestContext) the response for particular search operation to my Business layer, i will send this DTO(AddressResponseDTO) to PL.

But this is not always the case. Address Search request will be changed Sometimes i need to send only 3 properties (lets say City ,Zip and address Count)of it and sometimes it could be 5. So can i still have the same DTO with 20 proerties to reuse all kind of search request.

Comment: When you say n-tier and DTO - can you be explicit: are these logical boundaries? assembly boundaries? or inter-process/inter-machine boundaries? the terms are horribly overloaded, so it pays to be explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP states that sometimes only 3 of the properties are used, there can be several solutions:

- Create a DTO with all the properties, and specifiy special values to show which properties aren't specificed (i.e. use nullables, or special values). This requires lots of checkings in the code.
- Create a DTO with the 3 properties. Inherit a second DTO from this and add all the remaining properties. Your methods can receive the base class as parameter and check if a base or derived class is received. A simple check like `if (myDto is DtoBase) ...` will quickly show which properties have been sent with the DTO. (This will work only for increasing number of properties, in a hierarchy of inherited DTOs)
- If there are more than one possible grouping of properties of interest, you can use a DTO class for each group and:

  - create a class which has this DTO as members. If you don't need them, leave them null. This way you can check each group with a simple `if (containerDto.Dto1 != null)`
  - define as many DTO parameters as you need for each case.

I don't like the "special value" way, because it requires more code and it's more error prone. Besides, it makes you (de)serialize more info than neccessary on many occasions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no harm in writing a DTO with 20 properties.

However if the properties can be grouped together, it is better to group related properties into an entity, like you can group City, Zip into an address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, if the empty or default properties doesn't bother you in those cases. In theory there is nothing to prevent you using one class for all cases.

Or you can create several DTO class definitions, for the different use cases. In this case I suggest to use some class hierarchy between these classes.

I think it's up to you and the complexity of the use cases which way you prefer to use.